# How to render TIFF files in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rendering, tiff

The following script represents a Shiny app that loads an image file from the user's hard drive and prints it to the screen:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(fileInput("imported", "Import image file")),
    mainPanel(imageOutput("image"))
)
options(shiny.maxRequestSize = 100 * 1024 ^ 2) # to acommodate larger images
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$image <- renderImage({
        req(input$imported)
        list(
            src    = normalizePath(file.path(input$imported$datapath)),
            alt    = "there should be an image here",
            width  = 400,
            height = 400
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This works fine for regular image formats like PNG, but if I try to load a TIFF file it fails.

My goal is to write an app that loads multiple-page TIFF files and allows the user to browse through its pages, but I am stuck on even displaying a one-page TIFF file (samples are available [here](https://www.fileformat.info/format/tiff/sample/index.htm)).

Comment: There's no support for the TIFF format in many browsers. You can convert to PNG using the packages `tiff` and `png`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, thank you for the insight. A combination of `tiff::readTIFF` and `png::writePNG` did the trick.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio,  can you please share the editted code that worked... i've been struggling with similar problem.  i tried several imagemagick tricks with no luck.

Comment: @Hammao, the file I was working on is this one: https://github.com/ocbe-uio/cellmigRation/blob/shiny-page-4/Shinyapp/app.R Sorry it's not an MRE, but hopefully it's somehow still useful to solving your problem.