# How to render a TIFF file in a Shiny app (conversion to PNG format does not seem to work)

Tags: r, shiny, visualization

I want to make a simple app which lets me upload a local image file and render it on screen. Ideally, this should work for TIF(F) files. However, Shiny does not natively support TIFF files. As suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61380912/how-to-render-tiff-files-in-shiny), I tried a combination of `tiff:readTIFF` and `png::writePNG`, but I was not able to get it to work. As there were other people commenting on that post saying it didn't work I figured I might try posting it as a new question.

Below you can find the code I wrote for the `app.R` file. Tab 2 is where the image should be uploaded and visualized.

```
library(pacman)
pacman::p_load(shiny,shinydashboard,base64enc,tiff,png,here,jpeg,xfun,tidyverse)

#Header
header <-  dashboardHeader(title = "Visualization Tool")

#sidebar
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("1",tabName = "iris", icon = icon("magnifying-glass")),
    menuItem("2",tabName = "cars", icon = icon("fill")),
    menuItem("3",tabName = "test", icon = icon("puzzle-piece"))
  )
)

#body
body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem("cars",
            fluidPage(
              h1("Cars"),
              fileInput("upload","Upload image", accept=c("image/png","image/tif")),
              uiOutput("image")
            )
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input,output){

  tiff_image <- reactive({
    inFile <- input[["upload"]]
    if(!is.null(inFile$datapath)){
      if(xfun::file_ext(inFile$datapath)=="tif"){
        tiff::readTIFF(inFile$datapath,native=FALSE) %>%
          png::writePNG("test.png") 
        inFile$datapath <- readPNG("test.png")
        base64enc::dataURI(file = inFile$datapath, mime = "image/png")
      }
      else
      {
        base64enc::dataURI(file = inFile$datapath, mime = "image/png")
      }
    }
  })
  output[["image"]] <- renderUI({
    if(!is.null(tiff_image())){
      tags$div(
        tags$img(src= tiff_image(), width="100%"),
        style = "width: 400px;"
      )
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What the code should do is: upload a TIFF file chosen by the user, save it as a PNG file, read that PNG file and render it. I tried to upload a TIFF file in the upload section in tab 2, but I received following error message: `Warning: Error in $<-.data.frame: replacement has 480 rows, data has 1`. Uploading PNG images works just fine. I suspect that the error lies with storing the output of the readPNG function in `inFile$datapath`, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the conversion to png works for me, implementing it this way, (base64 conversion not needed)

```
library(tiff)
library(png)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("TIFF"),
  fileInput("upload","Upload image", accept="image/tiff"),
  imageOutput("img")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$upload, {   
    output$img<-renderImage({
      writePNG(
        readTIFF(input$upload$datapath, native = FALSE),
        target = "./img.png"
      )
      list(src = "./img.png",alt= "A PNG.")
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```